# How to use Jaspersoft Studio with UCanAccess?

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports, ucanaccess, jaspersoft-studio

I'm exhausted searching how I can connect Jaspersoft Studio to my database in Access using the Driver UcanAccess! I dont want to use OBDC anymore.

I already insert all jar files inside `lib/` folder to my Classpath:

[image]

I tried setting the **JDBC URL** Like this:

```
jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Phillips/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SaludParaTodos/src/Hospital.accdb;showSchema=true
```

and this:

```
jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Phillips/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SaludParaTodos/src/Hospital.accdb
```

[image]

But still getting the same error!

[image]

it seems that the program does not find the driver but it is inexplicable because I'm pointing the Classpath! (commons-lang-2.6,commons-logging-1.1.1,hsqldb,jackcess-2.1.3)

¿How I suppose to install that driver in Jasper Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the dependencies from the lib/ folder, *plus* the UCanAccess jar itself (e.g.,  ucanaccess-3.0.7.jar). That's five (5) jar files in total. And yes, your connection URL should include `;showSchema=true`.